# How to play redirected swf

Tags: javascript, redirect, flash, embed

I've got a embed code of a page with live streaming

```
<object id="myId" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" height="440" width="500">
            <param name="movie" value="http://play.shqiplive.info/new-topi4.swf">
            <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
            <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
            <param name="quality" value="high">
            <param name="flashvars" value="autostart=true&amp;overstretch=fit&amp;displayclick=fullscreen&amp;fghf=1111.&amp;bufferlength=2&amp;image=http://shqiplive.info/img/player.png&amp;logo=http://shqiplive.info/img/silver.png">
    <embed src="http://play.shqiplive.info/new-topi4.swf" wmode="transparent" allowfullscreen="true" quality="high" allowscriptaccess="always" flashvars="autostart=true&amp;overstretch=fit&amp;displayclick=fullscreen&amp;fghf=1111.&amp;bufferlength=2&amp;image=http://shqiplive.info/img/player.png&amp;logo=http://shqiplive.info/img/silver.png" height="440" width="500">

    </object>
```

but I can not play on my web because swf redirected to xxx.com. How to play this ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this SWF file seems to redirect you to this site itself. I can only imagine the cause of such behavior. For example you missed some necessary variables passed to the SWF. Or it was done for copyright protection purposses. Or something other.

The better way is to contact its authors or (a not very legal way) try to decompile it and look inside in order to detect what causes the redirect (probably `getUrl()` method call).

Comment: I tried with showmycode.com and nothing found ... :(
I know that in it is a server RTMP,is what I need.

Comment: You can try this tool: http://www.flash-decompiler.com/ solution to look inside the SWF. But have to warn you once again: most probably it's illegal :(